# How To Upload CSV To Algolia Using A Script

Tags: algolia

I would like to upload my CSV file using a PowerShell script. How is one able to accomplish this?

I was unable to find anything in the documentation. If there is something it should be searchable in the documentation.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I figured I'd post my solution. Just make sure that node.js and algolia-csv package is installed and then you can run the algolia-upload command from within PowerShell*

https://github.com/algolia/algolia-csv-js

NPM Manager (Which is packaged with Node)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm

Windows Installer - https://nodejs.org/en/download/

1. After installing "node-v6.11.1-x64" open the "node.js command
   prompt" application via the start menu
2. Run the following commands:
   npm install -g algolia-csv
3. Now you can prepare your command. (The CSV file must have headers in the first row only).

Options: algolia-upload $APP_ID $API_KEY $indexName $file|$url [-d $delimiter] [-b $batchSizer] [--clear-index] [--parse-arrays=$column]

Mandatory parameters are the aplication id, a key with write rights, the target index name and the input CSV (locally or accessible with http/https).

Other parameters:
-d let you set the delimiter used in your file. This should be set in quotes. Default is ','.
-b let you set the batch size. Default is 10000.
--clear-index forces the index to be cleared before uploading the new data.
--parse-arrays= let you specify if a column value should be splitted with ',' before uploading the data. More than one column can be set.
--geo-colums=latCol,longCol let you specify two columns that are to be used for creating the special algolia attribute _geoloc

This is the command that I ended up using just as a example.

algolia-upload APPID APIKEY INDEX PATH.csv

Answer (score 5):

As of November 2018, you can use the [Algolia CLI](https://github.com/algolia/algolia-cli) to easily import your JSON or CSV file(s) from your terminal:

- `$ npm i -g @algolia/cli`
- `$ algolia import -s path/to/your/file.csv -a your_app_id -k your_api_key -n your_index_name`

Answer (score 1):

we don't currently have an example written for PowerShell, but the steps it would come to are:

1. read the csv in PowerShell
2. convert the csv to JSON
3. push to the [API](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#addupdate-an-object-by-id) using curl

However, by going this route, you can't take advantage of the retry and DSN logic that's built into the Algolia API clients. You can use any of the [API clients](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/) to upload the data instead.

There's also a node [CSV toolbox](https://github.com/algolia/algolia-csv-js), which is a CLI to split and upload a csv file.

You can also upload it on the dashboard as [described here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/importing-data/importing-from-the-dashboard/#example-of-a-csv-file)